# Using javascript to populate a html table

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to add input where you can select different options for a location. my issue is that its messing up the table and it just does not see me new input option that i've added. I can list other files or pictures if needed.

[image: Before]

```
        var items = 0;
        function addItem() {
            items++;

            var html = "<tr>";
                html += "<td>" + items + "</td>";
                html += "<td><input type='number' name='idNumber[]'></td>";
                html += "<td><input type='text' name='itemName[]'></td>";
                html += "<td><input type='number' name='itemQuantity[]'></td>";

                html += "<td><select name='itemLocation[]' id='location'><option value="Shop" name="Shop">Shop</option></select></td>";

                html += "<td><input type='text' name='itemIndex[]'></td>";
                html += "<td><button type='button' onclick='deleteRow(this);'>Delete</button></td>"
                html += "</tr>";
```

[image: With trying to use input with different options]

Just trying to change to location button to a multiple choice selection

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add the minimal code you have, including HTML. Images only do not help us troubleshoot. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you have "shop" in double quotes, just like the string they're in. put a backslash before those quotes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have double quotes inside your string which is breaking your template
to avoid this kind of error you should use template literals its fully supported

**Note it is backtick (`) not singlequote (')**

see example

```
var value = "new entry"
var tr = `
<tr>
    <td>${value}</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
</tr>
`
```